# Error Running App from Heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku

I get the following error wile trying to run the app after deployment to Heroku. I can't figure out what the error is as the deployment was a success.

```
    2017-08-08T19:58:15.400596+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     node ./bin/www

    2017-08-08T19:58:15.400766+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
    2017-08-08T19:58:15.400935+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     npm bugs watchhours
    2017-08-08T19:58:15.401099+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
    2017-08-08T19:58:15.401267+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     npm owner ls watchhours
    2017-08-08T19:58:15.401434+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
    2017-08-08T19:58:15.407305+00:00 app[web.1]: 
    2017-08-08T19:58:15.407919+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
    2017-08-08T19:58:15.408104+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/npm-debug.log
    2017-08-08T19:58:15.497534+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
    2017-08-08T19:58:15.483131+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
    2017-08-08T19:58:28.070249+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=watch-hours.herokuapp.com request_id=08648f85-8ff8-4496-a1d0-4a59b656394b fwd="117.214.91.103" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
    2017-08-08T19:58:28.710982+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=watch-hours.herokuapp.com request_id=348cafa0-abb3-411f-a460-fdc52165e94f fwd="117.214.91.103" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

Comment: Can you show us some code?

Comment: You can find my repo here: https://github.com/MANOJPATRA1991/watchHours

Answer (score 1):

If you login to heroku you can see the logs for your project... your error will most likely be in there: https://dashboard.heroku.com/apps/you-app-name/logs

Comment: Hey I found the error and made the corrections. But now I get 

--------------at=info method=GET path="/" host=watch-hours.herokuapp.com request_id=e19afb5b-43c4-4bdc-a05b-cf47a32bc6e7 fwd="117.214.91.103" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=22ms status=302 bytes=352 protocol=https---------------

with no error code.